# AWS CLI v.s AWS Console for developement

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am a beginner in aws serverless.
I am now building 2 frontends using same aws serverless backend, and I am in the middle of the development.
I am currently using aws lambda, cognito, API Gateway, Dynamodb, IAM, S3 console.
Every time when I need to do something in the backend, I will go to the console and do it directly.

Recently I've discovered there is aws amplify framework and CLI which seems quite convenient.
I have a few questions for it:
1.What is the general pros and cons of using only console and using CLI for development?
2.Do you, or do most of the developers have preference for using one of it?
3.If I continue using only console for development, are there any problems foreseeable in the future?
4.If I change to use CLI for development, is there any difficulty to integrate my current work?

Comment: You should neither use the cli nor the console directly for production deployments directly (maybe other than some ***very*** critical, instant changes, e.g. closing a security group during an active attack). You should use an "infrastructure as code" tool like CDK, terraform, cloudformation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an **IaC Framework**, for example **AWS CloudFormation**. This way you can version your changes.

Only instant changes should happen via the console.

Comment: If I use IaC Framework, is it ok to keep my current work?

Comment: That could lead to difficulties. I would try to recreate the current infrastructure purely in code.

Comment: Is aws sam belong to IaC?

Comment: Yes you can use SAM in addition to CloudFormation